# Benefit to additional index with key column moved to includes

Tags: sql-server, index-tuning

Say I have an Index `Foo` with:

`Keys [A, B, C] and Included columns (D, E)`

Is there any performance reason to have an additional index `Bar` with:

`Keys [A, B] and Included columns (C, D, E)`

My assumption is that a non-needed key at the *end* would be treated the same as an included column.

Comment: I can think of several reasons why this would be harmful, no reasons why it would be helpful.

Comment: I guess you can come up with close to absurd cases. Like C being extremely wide and having another index with it ac included makes the non-leaf smaller (incl are only in leaf). Or extremely frequently modified (incl are not sorted, only stored). But IMO that would be such extremely cases so IMO that second index is redundant (and carries of course overhead).

Comment: Note: I have been working with indexes that SQL Server thinks are missing, and you will often end up with recommended indexes on a table that look like: `[A]`, `[A] include [B, F]`, `[A, B]`, `[A, B, F] include [C, D]`, and `[A, B] include [N, Q, X, R]`. Usually, these five can be covered by and index `[A, B, F] include [C, D, N, Q, X, R]`. However, if one of the INCLUDE values is large, e.g. `VARCHAR[8000] NOT NULL`, then having the one index that includes that separate from the others can be more efficient overall.

Comment: Thank you all for verifying my understanding. @LaughingVergil I think that is a good point to keep in mind, although in my case this is not an issue. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO, first we have to understand

1. How optimizer work ?
2. Optimizer will choose choose which index and WHY ?

As we know Optimizer make Cost base query plan. if query plan is not `Trivial` or `Simple` then it must be `Cost based Optimization`.

Example,

```
CREATE TABLE Test (
   id int identity(1,1) primary key
    A VARCHAR(50)
    ,B VARCHAR(50)
    ,C VARCHAR(50)
    ,D VARCHAR(100)
    ,E VARCHAR(100)
    )

INSERT INTO Test
WITH (TABLOCK) (
        A
        ,B
        ,C
        ,D
        ,E
        )
SELECT CONCAT (
        REPLICATE('A', 30)
        ,(rn / 5)
        )
    ,CONCAT (
        REPLICATE('B', 30)
        ,(rn / 5)
        )
    ,CONCAT (
        REPLICATE('C', 30)
        ,(rn / 5)
        )
    ,REPLICATE('D', 100)
    ,REPLICATE('E', 100)
FROM (
    SELECT TOP (1000000) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            ORDER BY (
                    SELECT NULL
                    )
            ) rn
    FROM sys.objects A
        ,sys.objects B
        ,sys.objects C
    ) t4

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX nc1_ABC ON Test (
    A
    ,B
    ,C
    ) include (
    D
    ,E
    )

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX nc2_AB ON Test (
    A
    ,B
    ) include (
    C
    ,D
    ,E
    )
```

In my example Index size of `nc1_ABC` will be more than `nc2_AB`. WHY ?

So if my query is,

```
SELECT A
        ,B
        ,C
        ,D
        ,E
    FROM test
    WHERE A = 'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA14372'
        AND B = 'BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB14372'
        and c='CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC14372'
```

Optimizer will choose `nc1_ABC` index.It will not use `nc2_AB`.

But if my query is

```
SELECT A
        ,B
        ,C
        ,D
        ,E
    FROM test
    WHERE A = 'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA14372'
        AND B = 'BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB14372'
        --and c='CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC14372'
```

Optimizer will choose `nc2_AB`. WHY ?

Because optimizer will compare the price of choosing `nc2_AB` and `nc1_ABC`.Optmizer will see that it has to find all record based on filter A and B, that is can do with both index  but index size of `nc2_AB` is less than `nc1_ABC`.So it will be use.

> Is there any performance reason to have an additional index Bar with:

So it depend upon example and how frequently the query is use and how important it is to get those record quickly.

If all those are correct then `additional index Bar` is require,
else `index Foo` is good enough for both query.

It really depend upon example and situation.