# Non Clustered Index using INCLUDE

Tags: sql-server

I am working on Consolidation INDEX.
I have 3 index on a table

```
Create NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX1 on TableA(a asc,b asc) INCLUDE(U,V,X,Y,Z)
Create NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX2 on TableA(a asc,b asc) INCLUDE(K,L,X,Y,Z)
Create NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX3 on TableA(a asc,b asc,c asc) INCLUDE(U,V,X,Y,Z)
```

So as the composite key is same and the order is also same.
I thought we can have 1 index rather than  3

```
 Create NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX4 on TableA(a asc,b asc,c asc) INCLUDE(U,V,X,Y,Z,K,L)
```

So , i have 2 Question:
**1 : Will creating new index for the 3 will work?**
**2 : Some developers tell me that difference in include statement as now I have (U,V,X,Y,Z,K,L) all in one can have significant difference in performance so ,I can't club them in 1?**

Comment: 1. Yes; 2. Yes, you can. Assuming that all 3 indexes are used regularly, having one larger index would be space/memory efficient than 3.

Comment: How many columns does `TableA` have? If all the columns that `TableA` has are U,V,X,Y,Z,K,L (and a,b,c) then consider removing the include statement.

Comment: TableA , has many columns

Comment: Analyze ,TableA will be query on which columns frequently and how many rows each rows such can fetch.So your answer also depend these question.You can read this https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/242673/benefit-to-additional-index-with-key-column-moved-to-includes/242729#242729

Answer (score 2):

1. Yes it will work.
2. It will have some difference in performance but will it be significant or not depends on the indexes usage. Scan operation will become more expensive because an index row is wider on the leaf level. On the other hand you will have one index in your buffer pool instead of three.

I would start from investigating the indexes current usage to make a reasonable decision.

Check `user_seeks`, `user_scans`, `user_lookups` columns:

```
    SELECT i.name, s.*,si.*
    FROM sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats s
        JOIN sys.indexes i ON i.object_id = s.object_id
            AND i.index_id = s.index_id
        JOIN sys.sysindexes si ON si.id = i.object_id
            AND si.indid = i.index_id
    WHERE s.object_id = OBJECT_ID('YourTableName')
        AND s.database_id = DB_ID()
    ORDER BY i.name
```

Check query plans for a particular index:

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED 
DECLARE @IndexName AS NVARCHAR(128) = 'IX1';

SET @IndexName = QUOTENAME(@IndexName); 

-- Dig into the plan cache and find all plans using this index 
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES 
   (DEFAULT 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/07/showplan')    
SELECT 
DB_NAME(x.dbid),
x.ObjectName,
stmt.value('(@StatementText)[1]', 'varchar(max)') AS SQL_Text, 
obj.value('(@Database)[1]', 'varchar(128)') AS DatabaseName, 
obj.value('(@Schema)[1]', 'varchar(128)') AS SchemaName, 
obj.value('(@Table)[1]', 'varchar(128)') AS TableName, 
obj.value('(@Index)[1]', 'varchar(128)') AS IndexName, 
obj.value('(@IndexKind)[1]', 'varchar(128)') AS IndexKind, 
x.plan_handle, 
x.query_plan 
FROM (
    SELECT try_CONVERT(XML, qp.query_plan) AS query_plan, cp.plan_handle, OBJECT_NAME(qp.objectid, qp.dbid) AS ObjectName, qp.objectid, qp.dbid
    FROM sys.dm_exec_cached_plans AS cp 
        JOIN sys.dm_exec_query_stats s ON s.plan_handle = cp.plan_handle
        cross apply sys.dm_exec_text_query_plan (s.plan_handle, s.statement_start_offset, s.statement_end_offset) AS qp 
) x
CROSS APPLY query_plan.nodes('/ShowPlanXML/BatchSequence/Batch/Statements') AS batch(stmt) 
CROSS APPLY stmt.nodes('.//IndexScan/Object[@Index=sql:variable("@IndexName")]') AS idx(obj) 
OPTION(MAXDOP 1, RECOMPILE);
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Yes you can combine them but shouldn't use them unless you have to
2) They may be right or wrong, need to test it in dev with same queries/workload to see.

I've heard that composite indexes are only helpful if you have a lot of queries hitting multiple columns at once.  Like:

```
select item from table where item => column1 and column2= 6 and column3 = 8000
```

It would make sense to combine three different indexes into one with most-used column1 first and include column2 and then column3 last.  ORDER DOES MATTER AND ALWAYS PUT MOST USED FIRST TO LEAST USED LAST

If you are mostly hitting tables with only 1 where clause, you should keep them separate from what I've heard.